# Boundary values in PDE using NDSolve - different outputs whether v.10.2 or 11.3

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I'm trying to solve the following PDE

$$\frac{\partial n(t,x)}{\partial t}=f(t,x)\frac{\partial^2n}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

with the boundary conditions
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}(t,x=0)=\frac{n}{\lambda_1}$$
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}(t,x=L)=-\frac{\lambda_2}{f(t,L)}$$

and initial condition
$$n(t=0,x)=\frac{1+x}{f(0,x)}$$

where $\lambda_{1,2}$ are constants.

If I use the code:

```
l1=2; l2=3; L=0.5;
f[t_,x_]:=x-1;

NDSolveValue[
{D[n[t, x], t] == D[f[t, x], x]*D[n[t, x], x] + f[t, x]*D[n[t, x], x, x] + 
NeumannValue[n[t, x]/l1, x == 0] + NeumannValue[-l2/f[t, x], x == L],
DirichletCondition[n[t,x] == (1+x)/f[t,x],t==0]},
n,
{t,0,1},
{x,0,L},
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}
]
```

then in Mathematica 10.2 the solution is fine but in Mathematica 11.3 I get the error:

```
NDSolveValue::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.
```

If I use the code

```
l1=2; l2=3; L=0.5;
f[t_,x_]:=x-1;

NDSolveValue[
{D[n[t, x], t] == D[f[t, x], x]*D[n[t, x], x] + f[t, x]*D[n[t, x], x, x],   
Derivative[0,1][n][t, 0]==n[t,0]/l1, 
Derivative[0,1][n][t,L]==-l2/f[t, L],
DirichletCondition[n[t,x] == (1+x)/f[t,x],t==0]},
n,
{t,0,1},
{x,0,L},
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}
]
```

I get the error in 10.2

```
CoefficientArrays::poly: -n/2 + n^(0,1)[t,0] is not a polynomial
```

and the error in 11.3 is the same as before:

```
NDSolveValue::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.
```

Why in the first case it works in the older version and not in the recent version? And why in the second case it doesn't work in any version (although with different errors...)?

Comment: Try pasting your code into a new session of *Mathematica* and running it.  I'm getting different errors, even if I fix the obvious syntax errors.  I think some things are missing from the code.

Comment: What is the dependent variable? `n`, `f` or `ne` or all of them?

Comment: Please see my original post: I've corrected the syntax errors (the mathematica errors are still the same though...) and also added values for the constants and a simple function f just for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial condition is not a `DirichletCondition`. Change the `DirichletCondition` to a proper initial condition. Like so:

```
NDSolveValue[{D[n[t, x], t] == 
   D[f[t, x], x]*D[n[t, x], x] + f[t, x]*D[n[t, x], x, x] + 
    NeumannValue[n[t, x]/l1, x == 0] + 
    NeumannValue[-l2/f[t, x], x == L], 
  n[0, x] == (1 + x)/f[0, x]}, n, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, L}, 
 Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}]
```

Now, this will give a message about IDA not being able to handle complex values, but that may not be an issue in your set up.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why using the Derivative[0,1]... instead of Neuman doesn't work?

Comment: @AJHC, see the section [NeumannValue and Formal Partial Differential Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) in the documentation.